# What to do when Smart UV Project never finishes

Tags: uv

I have an extremely complex model of a 3d satellite view of a part of a city created using Renderdoc and exported as an .rdc and imported into Blender.
I am following a YouTube tutorial which shows how to create just one material for all the materials in the model (my model has around 160 separate materials) and then baking it back to a copy of the model.
I have applied (mesh cleanup) Limited Dissolve Merge By Distance but still have over 300,000 faces.

The tutorial shows using Smart UV Project and warns the viewer that it can take a long time (he suggests jokingly to go and make and drink a coffee). When I perform the smart uv unwrap it has not completed 3 hours later!

The tutorial suggests exporting the model as an .obf and using a software tool named MESHLAB if you don't have time but warns it give inferior results.

Is that the only other method and what would I expect to see with "inferior results"?